# Grouping objects on the property in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, calculated-columns

I would like the Application and ShortcutName columns to be grouped into one column, while keeping the Version and Architecture columns as they are :

[image]

```
$object | Select-Object -Property Application, Version, Architecture, ShortcutName |
  Sort-Object -Property @{expression="Architecture";Descending=$true},Application | 
    Out-GridView
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell you group objects by properties with `Group-Object`. What you want is not grouping in that sense, but defining a new custom property.

You create custom properties a hashtable with the `Name` and `Expression` keys.

Something like this will probably do the trick.

```
$Expression = {
    if ($_.Application) {
        $_.Application
    } 
    else {
        $_.Shortcut
    } 
}

$object | 
    Select-Object -Property @{ Name = 'Application'; Expression = $Expression }, Version, Architecture | 
    Sort-Object -Property @{expression="Architecture";Descending=$true},Application | 
    Out-GridView
```

The expression checks whether the `Application` property is filled. If so, it will use the existing application name, otherwise it will take the `Shortcut` property as application name.

Comment: The Application property is always filled. I don't want substitute the Application property with the Shortcut property but have one column with the content of this 2 properties.